# Is operator == compatible with while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

got little code here :

```
class While 
{
public static void main(String args[])
  { 
    int n=10;
    while (n==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Print "+n);
        n--;
    }
  }
}
```

Dont understand why it wont print anything ? Is == operator compatible with while loop ?
It has no errors in code but it print nothing.

Comment: Your while loop isn't doing anything because n is not 0 but 10. Try with `n != 0` -> As long as n is not 0, loop

Comment: You are saying, "while `n` IS `0`, do this". `n` is initially 10, so the loop is never executed.

Comment: Just FYI if you're stuck and not going into debugging, just put a few print statments around and you'll see that n is 10 so the while loop will never run. Just a handy way to see things sometimes. System.out.println(n); before the loop,  then print something the while loop (you'll never see this) then after the while loop. Should give you an idea what's running/ not running.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `while` loop the wrong way. It should be

```
int n = 10;
while (n > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Print "+n);
    n--;
}
```

`while` is perfectly compatible with any logical operation but in your case `n` does not equal 0 at first so `while` won't execute.

Answer (score 5):

Your current condition does not allow the control to go in while loop. Change condition in while so that condition comes true until the value of n becomes zero.

```
int n=10;
while (n > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Print "+n);
    n--;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You initialize `n` to be `10`, which is different from `0`, therefore you never enter the `while` block.

I guess it's a typo, you just need to change the `while` condition to do what you want it to.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically saying  "while it is 0" which is not the case so your loop does not run.

You should say "while it is bigger than 0":

```
while(n > 0) {
  // ...
}
```

So basically it is not a compatibility issue but a logical failure.

Answer (score 3):

You have assigned int `n=10;`
So `while (n==0)` will always be `false` till n reaches 0.

You should change the condition to `while (n>0)`

Answer (score 2):

Just change in your code

```
while(n == 0) {
 ..........
}
```

with

```
while(n > 0) {
 ..........
}
```

it is only logical error.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

```
int n = 10;
while(n == 10) {
   System.out.println("This will run forever");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax :

```
while(Condition)
{
//these statements will be executed untill unless Condition evaluates to True
}
```

Statements inside `while` block will be Executed untill unless `Condition` evaluates to `True`

**in your code :** you initialised `n` to `10` and it is not equals to `0` hence it will be False, so it will not enter while loop to print anything

```
int n=10;
while (n==0)
{
//never enter here as n !=0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialized value for variable i is 10 in your code ( `int n=10;`).

The condition in while loop `n== 0` ( **10 == 0 always be false**) is never satisfied. For the code in while-loop body never execute. That is why there is nothing printed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will print the value of n once . NOTICE THE SEMICOLON AT THE END OF WHILE LOOP
.The block of statements ( statements 1 and 2 )are not at all inside the while loop .

```
int n=10;
while (n==0); // semicolon at the end of statement 
{
System.out.println("Print "+n);//-------1
n--;                           //-------2
}
```

OUTPUT :

The output will be : Print 10